# Logstash - Converting String to an Integer

Tags: logstash

In my Logstash I have below configuration:

```
filter {
   mutate {
        add_field => {
            "doclength" => "%{size}"
        }
        convert => {"doclength" => "integer"}
        remove_field => ["size"]
    }
}
```

I intend to store the field "**doclength**" into ElasticSearch as an **integer**. But somehow in ES, it shows mapping as "**string**" only.

Not sure what I am missing in here, the expected behavior is not matching up with the actual one.

Comment: Try to recreate your index. If it is created as string before these changes it will store as string unles you recreate it.

Comment: It was a new index altogether. One thing I see as problem is that it is do with the new field that I am adding and using convert function on it. If I directly apply convert function on "size" field and index it, then it shows as integer itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one, it worked on my machine.

```
filter {
   mutate {
        convert => {"size" => "integer"}
        rename => { "size" => "doclength" }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd sure love to know why this works, and why a simple convert without the rename doesn't.

Comment: @DaleC.Anderson Hi, have you known the reason?

Comment: @KeithTt I think its because you cannot change field types on the existing index, after its created. See https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-change-a-field-type/267382
You can reindex: https://linuxhint.com/change-field-type-elasticsearch/