# Parsing XML data from Filebeat using Logstash

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I am using Filebeat to parse XML files in Windows, and sending them to Logstash for filtering and sending to Elasticsearch.

The Filebeat job worked perfectly and I m getting XML blocks into Logstash, but it looks likes I misconfigured Logstash filter to parse XML blocks into separated fields and encapsulating these fields into an Elasticsearch type.

Here is my XML sample data:

> ```
> <H_Ticket>
>  <IDH_Ticket>26</IDH_Ticket>
>  <CodeBus>186</CodeBus>
>  <CodeCh>5531</CodeCh>
>  <CodeConv>5531</CodeConv>
>  <Codeligne>12</Codeligne>
>  <Date>20150915</Date>
>  <Heur>1110</Heur>
>  <NomFR1>SOUK AHAD</NomFR1>
>  <NomFR2>KANTAOUI </NomFR2>
>  <Prix>0.66</Prix>
>  <IDTicket>26</IDTicket>
>  <CodeRoute>107</CodeRoute>
>  <origine>01</origine>
>  <Distination>06</Distination>
>  <Num>6</Num>
>  <Ligne>107</Ligne>
>  <requisition> </requisition>
>  <voyage>0</voyage>
>  <faveur> </faveur>
>  </H_Ticket>
> <H_Ticket>
>  <IDH_Ticket>26</IDH_Ticket>
>  <CodeBus>186</CodeBus>
>  <CodeCh>5531</CodeCh>
>  <CodeConv>5531</CodeConv>
>  <Codeligne>12</Codeligne>
>  <Date>20150915</Date>
>  <Heur>1110</Heur>
>  <NomFR1>SOUK AHAD</NomFR1>
>  <NomFR2>KANTAOUI </NomFR2>
>  <Prix>0.66</Prix>
>  <IDTicket>26</IDTicket>
>  <CodeRoute>107</CodeRoute>
>  <origine>01</origine>
>  <Distination>06</Distination>
>  <Num>6</Num>
>  <Ligne>107</Ligne>
>  <requisition> </requisition>
>  <voyage>0</voyage>
>  <faveur> </faveur>
>  </H_Ticket>>     <H_Ticket>
>  <IDH_Ticket>26</IDH_Ticket>
>  <CodeBus>186</CodeBus>
>  <CodeCh>5531</CodeCh>
>  <CodeConv>5531</CodeConv>
>  <Codeligne>12</Codeligne>
>  <Date>20150915</Date>
>  <Heur>1110</Heur>
>  <NomFR1>SOUK AHAD</NomFR1>
>  <NomFR2>KANTAOUI </NomFR2>
>  <Prix>0.66</Prix>
>  <IDTicket>26</IDTicket>
>  <CodeRoute>107</CodeRoute>
>  <origine>01</origine>
>  <Distination>06</Distination>
>  <Num>6</Num>
>  <Ligne>107</Ligne>
>  <requisition> </requisition>
>  <voyage>0</voyage>
>  <faveur> </faveur>
>  </H_Ticket>
> ```

And here is my logstash config file:

```
input {  
    beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter 
{
    xml 
    {
        source => "ticket"
        xpath => 
        [
            "/ticket/IDH_Ticket/text()", "ticketId",
            "/ticket/CodeBus/text()", "codeBus",
            "/ticket/CodeCh/text()", "codeCh",
            "/ticket/CodeConv/text()", "codeConv",
            "/ticket/Codeligne/text()", "codeLigne",
            "/ticket/Date/text()", "date",
            "/ticket/Heur/text()", "heure",
            "/ticket/NomFR1/text()", "nomFR1",
            "/ticket/NomAR1/text()", "nomAR1",
            "/ticket/NomFR2/text()", "nomFR2",
            "/ticket/NomAR2/text()", "nomAR2",
            "/ticket/Prix/text()", "prix",
            "/ticket/IDTicket/text()", "idTicket",
            "/ticket/CodeRoute/text()", "codeRoute",
            "/ticket/origine/text()", "origine",
            "/ticket/Distination/text()", "destination",
            "/ticket/Num/text()", "num",
            "/ticket/Ligne/text()", "ligne",
            "/ticket/requisition/text()", "requisition",
            "/ticket/voyage/text()", "voyage",
            "/ticket/faveur/text()", "faveur"
        ]
        store_xml => true
        target => "doc"
    }
}

output 
{
    elasticsearch 
    { 
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "buses"
        document_type => "ticket"
    }
    file {
    path => "C:\busesdata\logstash.log"
}
stdout { codec =>rubydebug}
}
```

Filebeat configuration:

```
filebeat:
  # List of prospectors to fetch data.
  prospectors:
      paths:
        - C:\busesdata\*.xml
      input_type: log
      document_type: ticket
      scan_frequency: 10s
      multiline:
        pattern: '<H_Ticket'
        negate: true
        match: after
output:
  ### Logstash as output
  logstash:
    hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
    index: filebeat
```

And here is a portion of both stdout and file output:

```
PS C:\logstash-2.3.3\bin> .\logstash -f .\logstash_temp.conf
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 4
Pipeline main started

{
       "message" => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n<?xml-stylesheet href=\"ticket.xsl\" type=\"text/xsl\"?>\n<HF_DOCUMENT>",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-07-03T12:13:28.892Z",
        "source" => "C:\\busesdata\\ticket2.xml",
          "type" => "ticket",
    "input_type" => "log",
        "fields" => nil,
          "beat" => {
        "hostname" => "hp-pavillion-g6",
            "name" => "hp-pavillion-g6"
    },
        "offset" => 0,
         "count" => 1,
          "host" => "hp-pavillion-g6",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ]
}
{
       "message" => "\t<H_Ticket>\r\n\t\t<IDH_Ticket>1</IDH_Ticket>\r\n\t\t<CodeBus>186</CodeBus>\r\n\t\t<CodeCh>5531</CodeCh>\r\n\t\t<CodeConv>5531</CodeConv>\r\n\t\t<Codeligne>12</Codeligne>\r\n\t\t<Date>20150903</Date>\r\n\t\t<Heur>1101</Heur>\r\n\t\t<NomFR1>SOUK AHAD</NomFR1>\r\n\t\t<NomAR1>??? ?????</NomAR1>\r\n\t\t<NomFR2>SOVIVA </NomFR2>\r\n\t\t<NomAR2>??????</NomAR2>\r\n\t\t<Prix>0.66</Prix>\r\n\t\t<IDTicket>1</IDTicket>\r\n\t\t<CodeRoute>107</CodeRoute>\r\n\t\t<origine>01</origine>\r\n\t\t<Distination>07</Distination>\r\n\t\t<Num>3</Num>\r\n\t\t<Ligne>107</Ligne>\r\n\t\t<requisition> </requisition>\r\n\t\t<voyage>0</voyage>\r\n\t\t<faveur> </faveur>\r\n\t</H_Ticket>",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-07-03T12:13:28.892Z",
    "input_type" => "log",
        "source" => "C:\\busesdata\\ticket2.xml",
        "offset" => 125,
          "type" => "ticket",
         "count" => 1,
        "fields" => nil,
          "beat" => {
        "hostname" => "hp-pavillion-g6",
            "name" => "hp-pavillion-g6"
    },
          "host" => "hp-pavillion-g6",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `logstash`, enabling  `stdout { codec =>rubydebug}`?

Comment: I thought it's a matter of mapping, after manually setting the mapping of the type in ES and trying again, Logstash didn't send any data to ES... I'm pretty sure that it's a filter issue :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml filter won't work since the source configuration points to a field that does not exist.
There are no field `ticket` in your document:

```
{
    "message" => "\t<H_Ticket>\r\n\t\t<IDH_Ticket>1</IDH_Ticket>\r\n\t\t<CodeBus>186</CodeBus>\r\n\t\t<CodeCh>5531</CodeCh>\r\n\t\t<CodeConv>5531</CodeConv>\r\n\t\t<Codeligne>12</Codeligne>\r\n\t\t<Date>20150903</Date>\r\n\t\t<Heur>1101</Heur>\r\n\t\t<NomFR1>SOUK AHAD</NomFR1>\r\n\t\t<NomAR1>??? ?????</NomAR1>\r\n\t\t<NomFR2>SOVIVA </NomFR2>\r\n\t\t<NomAR2>??????</NomAR2>\r\n\t\t<Prix>0.66</Prix>\r\n\t\t<IDTicket>1</IDTicket>\r\n\t\t<CodeRoute>107</CodeRoute>\r\n\t\t<origine>01</origine>\r\n\t\t<Distination>07</Distination>\r\n\t\t<Num>3</Num>\r\n\t\t<Ligne>107</Ligne>\r\n\t\t<requisition> </requisition>\r\n\t\t<voyage>0</voyage>\r\n\t\t<faveur> </faveur>\r\n\t</H_Ticket>",
    "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-07-03T12:13:28.892Z",
    "input_type" => "log",
    "source" => "C:\\busesdata\\ticket2.xml",
    "offset" => 125,
    "type" => "ticket",
    "count" => 1,
    "fields" => nil,
    "beat" => {
        "hostname" => "hp-pavillion-g6",
        "name" => "hp-pavillion-g6"
    },
    "host" => "hp-pavillion-g6",
    "tags" => [
        [0] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ]
}
```

You should change the xml filter to:

```
 xml {
        source => "message"
        ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working! but I still have 2 issues: first, fields content is an array like that: "ticketId":["28"] and second, how can i apply a mapping to indicate each field type and format like i did in ES:PUT /transtu
{
    "mappings": {
        "ticket": {
            "dynamic":      "strict", 
            "properties": {
                "ticketId":  { "type": "integer"},
                "codeBus":  { "type": "integer"},
                "date":  { 
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "basic_date"
                },                  etc...

Comment: For the array problem you'll have to ask another question. Mapping: Elasticsearch automatically generates a mapping when you insert data in an index, according to the type of the data. So if your data in logstash is of the right type, the mapping will be right. You'll have to do conversion in your logstash filter (cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006656/logstash-converting-string-to-an-integer for string to int). You can also use an index template in Elasticsearch, but the data still has to be of the right type.

Comment: I fixed it using the mutate filter

Answer (score 2):

Can you try editing the `xpath` configuration in the `filter` as below:

```
filter 
{
    xml 
    {
        source => "ticket"
        xpath => 
        [
            "/IDH_Ticket/text()", "ticketId",
            "/CodeBus/text()", "codeBus",
            "/CodeCh/text()", "codeCh",
            "/CodeConv/text()", "codeConv",
            "/Codeligne/text()", "codeLigne",
            "/Date/text()", "date",
            "/Heur/text()", "heure",
            "/NomFR1/text()", "nomFR1",
            "/NomAR1/text()", "nomAR1",
            "/NomFR2/text()", "nomFR2",
            "/NomAR2/text()", "nomAR2",
            "/Prix/text()", "prix",
            "/IDTicket/text()", "idTicket",
            "/CodeRoute/text()", "codeRoute",
            "/origine/text()", "origine",
            "/Distination/text()", "destination",
            "/Num/text()", "num",
            "/Ligne/text()", "ligne",
            "/requisition/text()", "requisition",
            "/voyage/text()", "voyage",
            "/faveur/text()", "faveur"
        ]
        store_xml => true
        target => "doc"
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work, I got the same output, I think I this can be achieved using grok patterns, do you have any idea on how can I use grok patterns in this case?